# Android: How to create a layout similar to Calendar app - create event

Tags: android, layout, scroll, scrollview, footer

I'm trying to create a form very similar to the "Create event" screen of the native Calendar app on Android 2.x
Basically it has a fixed header, fixed footer and the middle is (I guess) a `ScrollView` with different "questions" such as "Event", "From", "To", "Location" etc...

I've tried a few options but I can't find the right layout that doesn't involve calculating the height of the screen

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by calculating the height? If it can scroll, there won't be any necessity to calculate the height.

Comment: Agreed, but then I'm having trouble positioning the fixed footer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a RelativeLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/status_header"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:paddingTop="8px"
    android:paddingBottom="8px"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/header_foreground"
    android:background="@color/header_background"
    android:text="@string/status_header"/>
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/statuspanel"
    android:layout_above="@+id/status_footer">
```

Put all your middle bits here, maybe in a TableLayout

```
</ScrollView>
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/status_footer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:paddingTop="4px"
    android:paddingLeft="2px"
    android:paddingRight="2px"
    android:stretchColumns="*"
    android:textColor="@color/footer_foreground"
    android:background="@color/footer_background">
    <TableRow>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/status_backbutton"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/status_backbutton" />
    </TableRow> 
</TableLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

You'll have to excuse all my colour bits, but you get the idea.
It's using alignParent elements in a RelativeLayout which is key, I think

Comment: shouldn't you be using `dp` instead of `px`?

Comment: Quite possibly. I'm not really up with how all this works to be honest. I'm designing my app for a minimum of 320x480 and letting the OS sort out any resizing

Comment: Thanks for your help, it's working exactly the way I needed it to.
I confirm from what I've read `dp` seems more standard than `px`